# Android: How to update spinner data on another fragment

Tags: android, fragment

So I have 2 fragments Fragment1 and Fragment2.  On an event in fragment 2 I would like to call the refreshSpinnerData method in Fragment1 to update the spinner in Fragment1.  I'm a novice, but being that Fragment1 is an object I'd think that I could just put the following line in Fragment2.  Fragment1.refreshSpinnerData();....but evidently that would just be too easy.  So how do I go about doing this?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please [edit] and add [tag:android] tag and use formatting tools and please add relevant code

Comment: I'm not sure what my specific code has to do with anything.  The question was a general question on the proper way to update a view in one fragment from a triggered event in another fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at [Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating).  In your case you would define the interface & callback in Fragment2, have your activity implement the interface, then find Fragment1 in your activity and call `.refreshSpinnerData()` on it.